# Matching against a GADTs specific type

Tags: haskell, gadt, data-kinds

With `DataKinds` and `KindSignatures`, I can do the following:

```
data T = T1 | T2 | ... | TN

data D (t :: T) where ...
  D1 :: ... -> D t
  D2 :: ... -> D t
  .
  .
  .
  DN :: ... -> D t
```

But of course, Haskell removes this type at runtime. I could keep this information by separating the constructors:

```
data D' (t :: T) where ...
  D1T1 :: ... -> D' T1
  D1T2 :: ... -> D' T2
  .
  .
  .
  D1TN :: ... -> D' TN
  D2T1 :: ... -> D' T1
  D2T2 :: ... -> D' T2
  .
  .
  .
  D2TN :: ... -> D' TN
  .
  .
  .
  DNT1 :: ... -> D' T1
  DNT2 :: ... -> D' T2
  .
  .
  .
  DNTN :: ... -> D' TN
```

And then when I pattern match, I've got the type also. But now I've blown out the number of constructors needed, and I suspect this will be a maintenance nightmare.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
data DWrap (t :: T) where
  DWrap :: t -> D t -> DWrap t
```

And then I can pattern match against `DWrap` to determine the type:

```
g :: D T1 -> ...
g = ...

f (DWrap T1 x) = g x
```

Which should be fine because once we match against `T1` we know `t` and then we know we it's the right type to start to pass to `g`.

Of course, if I just want to ignore the type I can like so:

```
h :: D t -> ...
h = ...

f (DWrap _ x) = h x
```

And either way completeness checking should make sure I don't do anything silly.

Except this approach won't work. Firstly, because `t` is not an ordinary type of kind `*`, it's of kind `T`. Secondly `T1` isn't even of type `'T1`, it's a member of the type `T`, just like `T2`, `T3` etc, so that's a useless approach to differentiating between types.

To attempt to solve the first problem, I could change `t` to `Proxy t`:

```
data DWrap (t :: T) where
  DWrap :: Proxy t -> D t -> DWrap t
```

Now this `data` definition compiles, but this is quite useless for differentiating between types, because `Proxy` only has one constructor.

I could do this:

```
data TConstructor (t :: T) where
  T1Con :: TConstructor T1
  T2Con :: TConstructor T2
  .
  .
  .
  TNCon :: TConstructor TN
```

And then this:

```
data DWrap (t :: T) where
  DWrap :: TConstructor t -> D t -> DWrap t
```

And then I could match like this:

```
g :: D T1 -> ...
g = ...

f (DWrap T1Con x) = g x
```

This should do the job, but I have to write out `data TConstructor`, which is almost a copy of `data T`. Is there anyway I could avoid this extra boilerplate and still achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Could you write a use case? It is pretty hard to understand what you are trying to do without concrete code to look at.

Comment: The use case if it helps (I'm not sure how it does) is dealing with expressions of various similar but slightly different types (there's a lot of overlap but some differences in behaviour). 

The code isn't concrete yet because I haven't written it because I'm unsure of the best approach (hence the question).

Comment: By use case, I mean *why* are you doing this, not *what* are you doing. It's hard to understand what you mean from these abstract types. *Why* do you need to "pattern-match" on types? Try to create a minimal version of the problem you are actually trying to solve that presents the same design challenges as the full problem so we can see what the true requirements are. That will help us help you :)

Comment: Why I'm doing this is because the current code is full of incomplete pattern matches and replication because the types don't accurately represent the values in question.

Comment: I'm not sure how I could make it more minimal. The reason why I've presented it like this is so it doesn't contain any extra information not relevant to my question. I could solve it badly and post that but it would be many hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: The library you're looking for is [singletons](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) which will allow you to generate `TConstructor` automatically (it'll probably be named `ST` for "singleton of T").

Comment: As other commenters mentioned, `singletons` is designed to solve precisely this problem. But in modern GHC it is really a very heavy-weight solution; you can make your life much easier by deriving `Typeable` instances for your types, and then using the type `data Sing_D (x :: D t) where MkSing_D :: Typeable x => Sing_D x` - this is essentially like your `TConstructor` solution, except `Typeable` is auto-generated by the compiler.

Comment: You have basically re-invented singletons. That's good! For the moment, we have to use those. Maybe one day GHC will allow non-erased types ("pi types") and we will be able to do without singletons.